# navigator.online always true

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, navigator

I am checking for changes in the `online` status of the app with `window` listeners, as explained in the [MDN page about online and offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events):

```
window.addEventListener('online', internetWentOnline, true);
window.addEventListener('offline', internetWentOffline, true);
```

The system was working fine, but now `navigator.online` is always `true`.

I did not make any significant change, except that I added PWA support with `@angular/service-worker`. Also, Chrome updated itself to version 68.0.3440.84 (64 bit).

Since on Firefox 61.0.1 (64 bit) the event listeners work as expected, I suspect this is caused by a bug of Chrome, possibly with PWA.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: Sounds like this would be better a as a [bug report](https://new.crbug.com) to Chrome.